# Why I have bad output using fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I'm getting wrong output using `fstream`.

I create a text file with 3 words in it. When I run the program from a text file I got the last word in the output twice (The word Apple I got twice in the output). I don't know why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fruit;
    int point = 0;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("darbas.txt");

    while(!infile.eof()){
        infile >> fruit;
        cout << fruit << endl;
        point++;
    }

    cout << "The number of fruit: " << point <<  endl;
    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be

> Banana, Orange, Apple, The number of fruit: 3

Actual output:

> Banana, Orange, Apple, Apple, The number of fruit: 4

Comment: Yay finally it's an exact dupe!

Comment: Now I tried to put infile >> fruit in !infile.eof() place, but the output was still wrong. It was Orange, Barana, The number of fruit: 2. Why It's still wrong.

Comment: Because you did not fully read the page I linked you to. You probably have two `infile >> fruit` now so you're discarding every other input. (Though it's not possible for Orange to be first, and now it's spelt "Barana"? Pay attention to details to avoid confusing the issue.)

Comment: Yes It's really true. I missed It somehow. Thank you, but how could I change It.

Comment: So you recognise the error but can't see how to fix it? I'll let you think for a while about how to do that, and about what each line of code in your program does.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what made you think `while(!infile.eof()){` was correct? We see this error over and over again, but why beginners make this mistake isn't usually clear.

Comment: I did It. Thanks that you let me to think about It.

Comment: @john I wached video on youtube and that man's code was good with !infile.eof(). Can you say me where !infile.eof() is usefull?

Comment: That man didn't know what he was talking about. The only time that `eof` is useful is when you know that a read has failed and you want to find out why it has failed. `eof` does not tell you if you are currently positioned at the end of file. So it's something you would use **after** you tried to read something, to tell you how that read went, not something you would use **before** you read, to tell you how the next read might go.

Comment: @John Thanks for your help.